# How do I select records with the most recent start date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to amend the below code that I didn't write and was handed over to me (relatively new to SQL), effectively it selects addresses however I only want to select addresses with the latest 'UDEFVALID_FROM' date, as currently if there are 2 addresses for a customer it will select both.

```
        Select * FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd 
        WHERE ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL 
          AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM 
              AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO
              OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL or ctd.UDEFVALID_TO>= GETDATE() ))
```

Just to further add onto this here is the full SQL:

```
IF @customer_rule = 'All'
      BEGIN
            insert into [etl].[lu_uletters_recipient_addrss_stg]
            (cnsmr_id,cnsmr_accnt_id,cnsmr_type,addrss_rule,recipientSalutation,recipientName,
            recipient_addressLine1,recipient_addressLine2,recipient_addressLine3,recipient_addressLine4,
            recipient_address_pstl_cd,recipient_primaryAddresseType,moreRecipientIndicator,PostalClass,dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm)
            select *
            from
            (
            select t.cnsmr_id as cnsmr_id,t.cnsmr_accnt_id as cnsmr_accnt_id,
            'Primary' as cnsmr_type,
            'All' as addrss_rule,
            ctad.UDEFSALUTATION AS recipientSalutation,
            isnull(ctd.UDEFNAME,ctad.UDEFADDRESSEE) as recipientName,
            COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt) as recipient_addressLine1,
            CASE WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt)
                  WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NOT NULL THEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt
                  WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NULL THEN NULL
            END as recipient_addressLine2,
            ctd.UDEFADDRESS_city_txt as recipient_addressLine3,
            ctd.UDEFADDRESS_st_txt as recipient_addressLine4,
            ctd.UDEFADDRESS_pstl_cd as recipient_address_pstl_cd,
            'P' as recipient_primaryAddresseType,
            'N' as moreRecipientIndicator,
            case when ctad.UDEFFOREIGN_ADDR_IND='Y' then 'O'
                  else t.PostalClass end as PostalClass,
            dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm
            from #tt_cnsmr t
            --inner join cnsmr_addrss cd on ( cd.cnsmr_id = t.cnsmr_id)
            --inner join cnsmr_accnt_ownrs CAO on (t.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = cao.cnsmr_accnt_id )
            inner join cnsmr_accnt CAO on (t.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = cao.cnsmr_accnt_id )
            left outer join UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id)
            left outer join UDEFADDITIONAL_CUST_DETAILS ctad on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctad.cnsmr_id)
            where t.dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm = @v_tmpl_code/*cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_typ_cd = 1
            and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_sft_dlt_flg = 'N'*/
            and ((ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO))
            OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL AND (GETDATE() >= isnull(ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'))))
            union
            select cao.cnsmr_id as cnsmr_id,cao.cnsmr_accnt_id as cnsmr_accnt_id,
            'Non-Primary' as cnsmr_type,
            'All' as addrss_rule,
            ctad.UDEFSALUTATION AS recipientSalutation,
            isnull(ctd.UDEFNAME,ctad.UDEFADDRESSEE) as recipientName,
            COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt) as recipient_addressLine1,
            CASE WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt)
                  WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NOT NULL THEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt
                  WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NULL THEN NULL
            END as recipient_addressLine2,
            ctd.UDEFADDRESS_city_txt as recipient_addressLine3,
            ctd.UDEFADDRESS_st_txt as recipient_addressLine4,
            ctd.UDEFADDRESS_pstl_cd as recipient_address_pstl_cd,
            'S' as recipient_primaryAddresseType,
            'N' as moreRecipientIndicator,
            case when ctad.UDEFFOREIGN_ADDR_IND='Y' then 'O'
                  else t.PostalClass end as PostalClass,
            dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm
            from #tt_cnsmr t
            inner join cnsmr_accnt_ownrs CAO on (t.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = cao.cnsmr_accnt_id )
            --inner join cnsmr_addrss cd on ( cd.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id)
            left outer join UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id)
            left outer join UDEFADDITIONAL_CUST_DETAILS ctad on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctad.cnsmr_id)
            where t.dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm = @v_tmpl_code
            and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_typ_cd = 2
            and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_sft_dlt_flg = 'N'
            and ((ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO))
            OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL AND (GETDATE() >= isnull(ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM,'1900-01-01 00:00:00'))))
            )stg_data
            where not exists ( select 1 from [etl].[lu_uletters_recipient_addrss_stg] t
                                   where t.cnsmr_id = stg_data.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = stg_data.cnsmr_accnt_id and t.dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm = @v_tmpl_code)
```

Comment: You need `max()` date with `group by` on rest of the columns in select list. Please do some homework. You'll learn something basic too.

Comment: Thanks for the response and yes you're right I do need to get to grips with the basics of SQL. I have been playing around with the max statement, like below but it's not working and I don't think it's along the lines of what you're suggesting, do I need to list out all the columns in the select as opposed to just use *:   Select * FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd WHERE
                                    (select max (ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sqlServer2008  +

Try

```
 ; With cte as (

    Select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by  UDEFVALID_FROM  desc) rn 
FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd
WHERE ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL 
      AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM 
          AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO
          OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL or ctd.UDEFVALID_TO>= GETDATE() ))
 )
Select * from cte where rn=1
```

Or use subQuery like

```
select * from (
    Select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by  UDEFVALID_FROM  desc) rn 
    FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address
)
where rn=1
```

your query after replace by subquery

```
 declare @v_tmpl_code nvarchar(10);

insert into [etl].[lu_uletters_recipient_addrss_stg] (cnsmr_id,cnsmr_accnt_id,cnsmr_type,addrss_rule,recipientSalutation,recipientName
, recipient_addressLine1,recipient_addressLine2,recipient_addressLine3,recipient_addressLine4
, recipient_address_pstl_cd,recipient_primaryAddresseType,moreRecipientIndicator,PostalClass,dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm) 
select * from ( select t.cnsmr_id as cnsmr_id,t.cnsmr_accnt_id as cnsmr_accnt_id, 'Primary' as cnsmr_type, 'All' 
as addrss_rule, ctad.UDEFSALUTATION AS recipientSalutation, isnull(ctd.UDEFNAME,ctad.UDEFADDRESSEE) as recipientName
, COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt) as recipient_addressLine1
, CASE WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt) 
WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NOT NULL 
THEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NULL 
THEN NULL END as recipient_addressLine2, ctd.UDEFADDRESS_city_txt as recipient_addressLine3, ctd.UDEFADDRESS_st_txt
 as recipient_addressLine4, ctd.UDEFADDRESS_pstl_cd as recipient_address_pstl_cd, 'P' as recipient_primaryAddresseType
 , 'N' as moreRecipientIndicator, case when ctad.UDEFFOREIGN_ADDR_IND='Y' then 'O' else t.PostalClass 
 end as PostalClass, dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm 
 from #tt_cnsmr t 

 inner join cnsmr_addrss cd on ( cd.cnsmr_id = t.cnsmr_id) 
 inner join cnsmr_accnt_ownrs CAO on (t.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = cao.cnsmr_accnt_id ) 
 inner join cnsmr_accnt CAO on (t.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = cao.cnsmr_accnt_id ) 

 -- this is the replaced query
 left outer join (Select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by UDEFVALID_FROM desc) rn FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address) ctd on t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id and ctd.rn=1

 left outer join UDEFADDITIONAL_CUST_DETAILS ctad on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctad.cnsmr_id) 
 where t.dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm = @v_tmpl_code and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_typ_cd = 1 
 and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_sft_dlt_flg = 'N'
  and ((ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM 
 AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO)) OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL AND (GETDATE() >= isnull(ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM,'1900-01-01 00:00:00')))) 

 union 

 select cao.cnsmr_id as cnsmr_id,cao.cnsmr_accnt_id as cnsmr_accnt_id, 'Non-Primary' as cnsmr_type, 'All' as addrss_rule, 
 ctad.UDEFSALUTATION AS recipientSalutation, isnull(ctd.UDEFNAME,ctad.UDEFADDRESSEE) as recipientName
 , COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt) 
 as recipient_addressLine1, CASE WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NOT NULL 
 THEN COALESCE(ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt,ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt) 
 WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NOT NULL 
 THEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_3_txt WHEN ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt IS NULL AND ctd.UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_2_txt IS NULL 
 THEN NULL END as recipient_addressLine2, ctd.UDEFADDRESS_city_txt as recipient_addressLine3, ctd.UDEFADDRESS_st_txt 
 as recipient_addressLine4, ctd.UDEFADDRESS_pstl_cd as recipient_address_pstl_cd, 'S' as recipient_primaryAddresseType, 'N' 
 as moreRecipientIndicator, case when ctad.UDEFFOREIGN_ADDR_IND='Y' then 'O' else t.PostalClass end as PostalClass, dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm 
 from #tt_cnsmr t inner join cnsmr_accnt_ownrs CAO on (t.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = cao.cnsmr_accnt_id ) 
 inner join cnsmr_addrss cd on ( cd.cnsmr_id = cao.cnsmr_id) left outer join UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id) 
 left outer join UDEFADDITIONAL_CUST_DETAILS ctad on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctad.cnsmr_id) where t.dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm = @v_tmpl_code
  and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_typ_cd = 2 and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_sft_dlt_flg = 'N' and ((ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL 

  AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO)) OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL 
  AND (GETDATE() >= isnull(ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM,'1900-01-01 00:00:00')))) )stg_data where 
  not exists ( select 1 from [etl].[lu_uletters_recipient_addrss_stg] t
   where t.cnsmr_id = stg_data.cnsmr_id and t.cnsmr_accnt_id = stg_data.cnsmr_accnt_id and t.dcmnt_tmplt_shrt_nm = @v_tmpl_code)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Eid. I receive and error message saying incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over' do I need to make some changes specific to my tables?

Comment: It was in row_ number,it must be row_number()

Comment: Wow thanks Eid I think that returns just the subset I needed! I now just need map it into the larger piece of SQL I've been handed over

Comment: Add your query inside cte clause  and add the rownumber to it like  ;with cte as(.....your query here ) select * from cte where rn=1

Comment: I’ve added the where clause from your question to the answer

Comment: Once again can't thank you enough Eid, returns the subset I need! The only question I have is that the clause I have for the Valid_From date actually enter the code within an and statement (it's a big piece of SQL so I was just testing separately using the select from UDEF_CustTemp_Address, therefore is it possible to add the 'with cte as'  after an and statement? I've posted the start of the SQL below if it helps: 'and cao.cnsmr_accnt_ownrshp_sft_dlt_flg = 'N'
            and ((ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO))'

Comment: No you can’t add cte clause after and , so post your full query then we can help you.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot Eid, I've put the actual SQL in the main comment as it's too long for this, the key thing is I only require 1 address for cnsmr_id (the max UDEFVALID_FROM date)

Comment: I think you can use subquery instead of table "UDEFCust_Temp_Address" use. subquery --  (Select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by  UDEFVALID_FROM  desc) rn 
    FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address)  as ctd on t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id and ctd.rn=1.

Comment: Thanks Eid, so whereabouts would I insert that in the code, after flg ='N'?  Also I recieve an error message around the 'on', do I need to add a join? In hindsight I think I'm far too inexperienced to pick this task up but I do really appreciate the help!

Comment: instead of   " left outer join UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd on ( t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id). ".  use   "  left outer join (Select *, row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by UDEFVALID_FROM desc) rn FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address) ctd on t.cnsmr_id = ctd.cnsmr_id and ctd.rn=1   "

Comment: Brilliants thanks, still having trouble with 'on' in that statement, incorrect syntax, it will most likely be me missing something obvious?

Comment: I've edited the answer by correct query after replying the join by the subquery, I've tested the syntax also.

Comment: Eid I owe you more than 1, massively appreciate it thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by group & order clause, as below (replace custId  with the correct column name for base on what you want address in group by)  :

```
Select * FROM UDEFCust_Temp_Address ctd WHERE
                                ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM IS NOT NULL AND (GETDATE() >= ctd.UDEFVALID_FROM AND GETDATE() <= ctd.UDEFVALID_TO
        OR (ctd.UDEFVALID_TO IS NULL or ctd.UDEFVALID_TO>= GETDATE() ))
        group by custId order by UDEFVALID_TO desc
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Chandan. So I swapped custId with cnsmr_id (relevant column) but I receive and error with another column in the table stating it is invalid as is it not contained in either an aggregate function or GROUP BY clause, do you have any thoughts please?

Comment: Yes, this error is dependent on SQL version. Instead of select *, put columns name i selection and also same in order by.

Comment: Ah fantastic thank you Chandan! That works now, so if one customer (cnsmr_id) has 2 address and I only want to select 1 address based on the MAX valid_from date how would I go about doing that? Apologies if I'm missing the obvious as the select statement currently returns 2 address for the 1 customer

Comment: Bad answer. With `GROUP BY custId` you aggregate your data such as to get one result row per `custId`. Now in your select clause you must specify which aggregations for a `custId`, e.g. the `MAX(UDEFVALID_TO)`, `MIN(UDEFADDRESS_addrss_ln_1_txt)` etc. `SELECT *` is plain wrong in combination with `GROUP BY`. And if you want complete records as stated in the request, then is is the wrong approach altogether. Use `ROW_NUMBER` as shown in the other answer.

Comment: `ORDER BY` occurs after `GROUP BY` by the way and hence doesn't alter its results.

Comment: Thanks for replying Thorsten, I'm going with (or attempting to!) Eid's suggestion of row_number